# how to implement a camera function in pygame that follows the player and have sides aligned to the borders?

Tags: python, pygame, camera, 2d

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

from assets import Assets
from player import Player


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()

        self.win_w = pygame.display.Info().current_w
        self.win_h = pygame.display.Info().current_h

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((self.win_w, self.win_h), pygame.RESIZABLE | pygame.SCALED)
        self.screen_rect = self.screen.get_rect()
        self.surface = pygame.surface.Surface((self.win_w, self.win_h))

        pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

        self.clock = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.fps = 60
        self.assets = Assets(self.screen.get_rect())
        self.running = True

        self.entities = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = Player(0, self.win_h, self.win_w, self.win_h)
        self.player.assets = self.assets
        self.player.load_assets()

        self.entities.add(self.player)

    def main(self):
        while self.running:
            # --- events ---
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    self.running = False


            # --- draw on surface ---
            self.surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
            self.surface.blit(self.assets.bknd, self.assets.bknd_rect)

            self.player.update()
            print(f"Player Position (x={self.player.rect.x} y={self.player.rect.y})")

            for e in self.entities:
                self.surface.blit(e.image, e.rect)

            # --- modify surface ---
            mod = self.surface.copy()

            # zoom
            scale = 1.5
            mod = pygame.transform.rotozoom(mod, 0, scale)
            mod_rect = mod.get_rect()

            # Calculate the scaled background dimensions
            scaled_bknd_width = self.assets.bknd.get_width() * scale
            scaled_bknd_height = self.assets.bknd.get_height() * scale

            print("Scaled bknd w", scaled_bknd_width)
            print("Scaled bknd h", scaled_bknd_height)

            # Determine the bounds for the camera
            max_camera_x = scaled_bknd_width - self.screen_rect.width
            max_camera_y = scaled_bknd_height - self.screen_rect.height

            print("Max cam x", max_camera_x)
            print("Max cam y", max_camera_y)

            # Calculate the desired camera position (centered on the player, considering scaling)
            desired_camera_x = (self.player.rect.centerx * scale) - self.screen_rect.centerx
            desired_camera_y = (self.player.rect.centery * scale) - self.screen_rect.centery

            print("Desired cam x", desired_camera_x)
            print("Desired cam y", desired_camera_y)

            # Clamp the camera position within the background boundaries
            camera_x = max(0, min(desired_camera_x, max_camera_x))
            camera_y = max(0, min(desired_camera_y, max_camera_y))

            print("Cam x", camera_x)
            print("Cam y", camera_y)

            # Apply the camera position with correct sign
            mod_rect.x = -camera_x
            mod_rect.y = -camera_y

            # --- draw surface on screen ---
            self.screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            self.screen.blit(mod, mod_rect)

            pygame.display.flip()
            self.clock.tick(self.fps)

            print()
```

I am trying to create a 2d sidescroller game in pygame and I am stuck on creating a camera function that is able to follow the player around. Currently, I have a minimal application which is only able to align the top and left sides. If my character goes to the right too far, the outside of the background is able to be seen. How would you fix this while implementing a zooming factor as well to zoom onto the player and follow it?

Thank you very much